# Getting a Select2 dropdown with Ajax working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, jquery-select2

I have imported the scripts and formatting for select2, and followed the guides as well as tried things people have suggested in answer to similar questions but am getting nowhere so I thought I'd ask here, and I appreciate any help offered.

I want a select2 dropdown that, as you type, calls a function in the controller given what you've typed and that returns contacts from the db with that text in their names, which goes back to the view and populates the dropdown, dynamically.

This is the dropdown code:

```
<select class="form-control select2-container--bootstrap4" id="telephone-contacts-list"></select>
```

Here's the javascript. It's a bit all over the place because I've been trying loads of different things as mentioned:

```
$('#telephone-contacts-list').select2({
                theme: 'bootstrap4',
                minimumInputLength: 2,
                placeholder: "Search for a contact...",
                allowClear: true,
                ajax: {
                    delay: 250,
                    url: 'GetContactsList',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: function (params) {
                        var query = {
                            search: params.term,
                            type: 'public',
                            detailType: "telephone"
                        }

                        // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&type=public
                        return query;
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return { results: data };
                    }

                },
                formatResult: itemFormatResult,
                formatSelection: function (item) {
                    return item.name;
                },
                escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
            });

        function itemFormatResult(item) {
            var markup = "<option value='" + item.value+"'>"+item.name+"</option>";
            return markup;
        }
```

This is the controller function that returns a serialised object that has name and value fields:

```
Public Function GetContactsList(search As String, type As String, detailType As ContactDetailModel.DetailType) As JsonResult
            Dim l
            l = (From c In DB.Contacts Order By c.PrimaryName.FullName Descending Select New With {.name = c.PrimaryName.FullName, .value = c.ID}).ToArray
            Return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

Note, I want the dropdown to populate in such a way that the name property of the select list to map to the name property and the select list value property to map to the value property for each item, so can I do further javascript wizardry with it later.

So yes, could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong and what I need to do right to get it working as intended? As you can probably see, I am a fairly new programmer and therefore might struggle with answers that require too much background knowledge, but still, I'd accept those over nothing so any help is very much appreciated!

Cheers